# How do I set a loop so that it generates a new random number if one number is too similar to another?

Tags: python

I'm trying to generate (pseudo)random numbers using the random module. I need the numbers generated to not be too close to each other in terms of range. For example, if a number of n is generated, then another number x cannot be n +- 5.

```
from random import randint

i = 10

j_list = []
k_list = []

while i != 0:

    j = randint(-10, 10)
    k = randint(-15, 15)

    j_list.append(j)
    k_list.append(k)

    i -= 1

print("J list is: {} and K list is {}".format(j_list, k_list))
```

For example, when I ran it last time, I got following output:

```
J list is: [-4, 5, 2, -3, 7, -4, 3, -1, -1, -6] and K list is [10, 3, -7, -1, -5, -11, 3, 8, 1, -7]
```

As you can see, the 1st and 3rd elements of j_list (that is, j_list[1:3]) are within +- 5 of one another. This is not something I want; I want every element in the list to produce values that are out of certain range.

Is there any way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, using a for loop is better than using a while loop here:

```
# One line and you know the loop range immediately
for i in range(10):
    print(i)

# Three lines and takes the reader two seconds to comprehend
i = 10
while i != 0:
    i -= 1
    print(i)
```

Now to answer your question, you can use random.choice to exclude range(j - 5, j + 5):

```
from random import randint, choice

j_list = []
k_list = []

for i in range(10):

    j = randint(-10, 10)
    k = choice([n for n in range(-15, 15) if n not in range(j - 5, j + 6)])

    j_list.append(j)
    k_list.append(k)

print("J list is: {} and K list is {}".format(j_list, k_list))
```

If you only want to use randint, an alternative is to use a while loop to keep rerolling value k until it does not fall in the j +- 5 range:

```
from random import randint

j_list = []
k_list = []

for i in range(10):

    j = randint(-10, 10)
    k = randint(-15, 15)

    while abs(j - k) <= 5:

        k = randint(-15, 15)

    j_list.append(j)
    k_list.append(k)

print("J list is: {} and K list is {}".format(j_list, k_list))
```

As @ShadowRanger points out, the while loop strategy is less computational demanding and is easier to read so you might want to go for that.

Comment: The `for` loop in your example isn't really the same as the `while` loop, as the latter counts down rather than up. Of course, since `i` isn't being used by the questioner's code, it doesn't matter here. If it did, you'd want to use `for i in range(10, 0, -1):`.

Comment: The `while` loop to regenerate `k` isn't terrible; I'd generally discourage the `choice` based code as it does a fairly ridiculous amount of guaranteed work (generating a complete temporary `list` of all possible values, including recreating the `range(j - 5, j + 5)` object over and over again) to avoid a small amount of retry work; it gets *more* expensive as the odds of producing the wrong value go *down*, where retry loops get cheaper, so when it really matters, the `choice` solution given will perform the worst.

Comment: Also, side-note: If I'm reading the OP correctly, any number +- 5 from `j` is bad. So your `choice` solution should be filtering on `not in range(j - 5, j + 6)` (because `range`s aren't inclusive on the end), and the loop solution should be looping on `while abs(j - k) <= 5:` (or equivalently, and likely slightly faster `while -5 <= j - k <= 5:`), so `j - 5` and `j + 5` are excluded, not just `j - 4` through `j + 4`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree that the retry loop is computationally cheaper, and it is also easier to read as well. And you are absolutely right. I corrected the mistakes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is not to filter out bad values, but to prevent them from ever occurring in the first place. An easy solution is to generate a more restrictive range of numbers (as large as the overall bounds, minus the numbers to exclude), then add the size of the omitted numbers to the result if the result is equal to or greater than the bottom of the excluded range.

```
from random import randint

i = 10

j_list = []
k_list = []

too_close = 5    

while i != 0:

    j = randint(-10, 10)
    k = randint(-15, 15 - (too_close * 2 + 1))  # excluding j +- 5 means 11 numbers we won't use
    # The range from j - 5 to 4 is logically j + 6 to 15, so when we
    # generate a number of j - 5 or higher, we add 11 to adjust it to the desired result
    if k >= j - too_close:
        k += too_close * 2 + 1

    j_list.append(j)
    k_list.append(k)

    i -= 1

print("J list is: {} and K list is {}".format(j_list, k_list))
```

This should win on performance for a PRNG of any complexity, since it means you never generate *any* additional random numbers; there is no "test for bad and generate new loop" or the like, because you make sure you've generate valid numbers directly.

Side-note:

```
i = 10
while i != 0:
    ...
    i -= 1
```

where `i` is otherwise unused is a pointlessly complicated way to spell:

```
for i in range(10):
    ...
```

Or if i must descend from 10 to 0:

```
for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    ...
```

Either `for` will outperform the `while`, and be significantly less error prone (can't forget to adjust `i` or skip the adjust step via `continue` or the like).

Answer (score -1):

How about something along these lines, this you can easily alter the amount of `iterations`, the range of your `randint` and the permissible space between your `randint`

```
from random import randint

def not_within_five(lista):
    i = 0
    while i < 10:
        x = randint(0, 50) 
        if lista[i] in range(x-5, x+5):
            continue
        else:
            lista.append(x)
            i += 1

j = []
k = []

j.append(randint(0, 50))
k.append(randint(0, 50))

not_within_five(j)
not_within_five(k)

print(f"J list is {j}\n")
print(f"K list is {k}")
```

**Output**

> ```
> (xenial)vash@localhost:~/python$ python3.7 randi.py
> J list is [19, 31, 49, 3, 9, 42, 29, 41, 22, 0, 35]
>
> K list is [42, 19, 13, 27, 42, 1, 26, 10, 17, 40, 47]
> ```